# No visible @interface for "NSMutableArray" devlares the selector 'addObject:initWithBackgroundImage:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I'm finding this error in my project

No visible @interface for "NSMutableArray" devlares the selector 'addObject:initWithBackgroundImage:'

here is the background.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface background : NSObject


@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *backgroundImage;

-(id)initWithBackgroundImage:(NSString *)bImage;

@end
```

and the background.m

```
#import "background.h"

@implementation background
@synthesize backgroundImage;

-(id)initWithBackgroundImage:(NSString *)bImage{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    backgroundImage = bImage;

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

here is the problem in my code when I try to get the background from server

```
-(void) getBackgroundImage{
    NSURL *backgroundURL = [NSURL URLWithString:getBackground];
    NSData *backgroundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:backgroundURL];

    backgroundJason = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:backgroundData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    backgroundArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i<backgroundArray.count; i++) {
        NSString *bImage = [[backgroundArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"background_image"];

        [backgroundArray addObject:[background alloc] initWithBackgroundImage:bImage];
    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more brackets. This,

```
[backgroundArray addObject:[background alloc] initWithBackgroundImage:bImage];
```

should be this,

```
[backgroundArray addObject:[[background alloc] initWithBackgroundImage:bImage]];
```